# Compact manifold with smooth boundary embedded isometrically into compact manifold without boundary with same dimension as original one.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

Let $(M, g)$ be a compact manifold with a smooth boundary. There is a compact connected manifold without boundary $(N, g)$ having the same dimension as $M$ so that $(M, g)$ is isometrically embedded in $(N, g) .$

I can prove this theorem for a special case if $M\subset \mathbb R^n$.

Consider some cube $N=$ $[-K, K]^{n}$ with $M \subset N^{\text {int }}$, and  extend $g$ smoothly as a $2 K$ -periodic positive definite symmetric matrix function in $N$.

But in general how to prove a given statement?

Any hint/help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the metric in a neighborhood of $\partial M$ is a product metric, then you can take $N$ to be the [double of $M$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_(manifold)).

Comment: If the boundary is totally geodesic, (that is a geodesic that is tangent somewhere to the boundary stays in the boundary), then one can take $N$ to be its double.

Comment: If not, I think -but I have no proof- that one can glue a colar near the boundary and extend smoothly the metric in this colar to create a situation where we can use the first idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N_1$ be the double of $M$. Since $M$ is compact, so is $N_1$. Since $M$ is compact, it has only finitely many component. Then by forming finitely many connected sums (away from $M \subset N_1$), we assume that $M$ is embedded in a connected compact manifold $N$ without boundary with the same dimension.

Extending the metric $g$ from $M$ to $N$ is standard: for each $x\in M$, since $g$ is smooth, there is some neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $N$ and a smooth metric $g_x$ on $U_x$ so that $g_x(y) = g(y)$ for all $y\in M\cap U_x$. Let $\{\varphi_0\} \cup  \{\varphi_x : x\in M\}$ be a partition of unity subordinated to $\{ U_0 = N\setminus M\} \cup \{ U_x: x\in M\}$. Let $g_0$ be any smooth metric on $U_0$. Then

$$ h = \varphi_0 g_0 + \sum_{x\in M }\varphi _x g_x$$
is a smooth metric on $N$ and $h = g$ on $M$.