# How to show exit time is continuous on unit sphere bundle $SM$?

Tags: differential-geometry, continuity, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be riemannian manifold.

Unit sphere bundle $SM=\{(x,v):x\in M,|v|_g=1\}$. Given $(x, v) \in S M$, let $\gamma_{x, v}$ denote the unique geodesic determined by $(x, v)$ so that $\gamma_{x, v}(0)=x$ and $\dot{\gamma}_{x, v}(0)=v$. For any $(x, v) \in S M$ the geodesic $\gamma_{x, v}$ is defined on a maximal interval of existence that we denote by $\left[-\tau_{-}(x, v), \tau_{+}(x, v)\right]$ where $\tau_{\pm}(x, v) \in[0, \infty]$, so that
$$
\gamma_{x, v}:\left[-\tau_{-}(x, v), \tau_{+}(x, v)\right] \rightarrow M
$$
is a smooth curve that cannot be extended to any larger interval as a smooth curve in $M$.

If $(x, v) \in S M$, let $\tau(x, v) \in[0, \infty]$ be the first time when $\gamma_{x, v}(t)$
exits $\boldsymbol{M}$
$$
\tau(x, v):=\sup \left\{t \geq 0 ; \gamma_{x, v}([0, t]) \subset M\right\}
$$
We call $(M, g)$ non-trapping, if $\tau(x, v)<\infty$ for each $(x, v) \in S M$.

Let $(M, g)$ be a compact non-trapping manifold with strictly convex boundary. Then we have to show that $\tau$ is continuous map.
Intuitively, I can imagine that if $(x_1,v_1)$ and $(x_2,v_2)$ are close to each other. then there exit time also close to each other. But I don't know how to make that proof rigourous.

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Does SM mean semimartingales?

Comment: @Saad SM is unit sphere bundle

Comment: One possibly useful tool is to choose a boundaryless extension $\widetilde{M}$ and a smooth defining function $\psi:\widetilde{M}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $M=\psi^{-1}([0,\infty))$ and $\operatorname{grad}\psi|_{\partial M}=-N$. You can then argue that that zeros of $\psi\circ\gamma_{(x,v)}$ depend continuously on $(x,v)$.

Comment: What is $\gamma$ here?

Comment: Where does the geodisic exist when it 'exits' the manifold? Or should the condition in the definition of exit time instead be $\gamma_{x,v}([0,t])\subset$ int$(M)$?

Comment: @dennis_s By closed extension theorem, we can embed any compact manifold with smooth boundary $M$ into a compact manifold without boundary of same dimension. For proof you can see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4121150/compact-manifold-with-smooth-boundary-embedded-isometrically-into-compact-manifo.   Once we have compact manifold with out boundry we can invoke Hopf renow theorem, so geodesic travel indefinitly there. Geodesic exits $M$ means first time enter $N\setminus M$ region.

Comment: @idon'tknow This might be way to prove that, as Kajelad mentioned earlier, though I doubt that it is necessary to extend the manifold. This way you would also have to extend the Riemannian metric and would have to prove independence of that, while entering the boundary might be an easier equivalent condition, since the boundary is already geodesically convex.

Comment: I could imagine that one could 'attack' the problem by topologizing the space of continuous paths on $M$ using the Riemannian metric $g$. The intent would be to show that the geodesic flow $\gamma$ mapping a point $(x,v)\in SM$ to its unique geodesic is continuous.

Comment: @Kajelad I can prove that such boundary defining function $\psi$ is smooth on extension.  Also composition of curve is also smooth. But how that related to exit time function, still I could not convince. Can you please through some light on that? Thanks.

Comment: Working locally around $(x_0,v_0)$ we can define $c_{(x,v)}:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $c_{(x,v)}=\psi\circ\gamma_{(x,v)}$, where $T>\tau(x_0,v_0)$. These form a $C^1$ family, in that $\forall \epsilon>0$ there is always an open neighborhood $U\ni(x_0,v_0)$ such that $\max|c_{(x,v)}-c_{(x_0,v_0)}|<\epsilon$ and $\max|c_{(x,v)}'-c_{(x_0,v_0)}'|<\epsilon$ for $(x,v)\in U$. This should be enough to bound the variation of the exit time $\tau(x,v)=\inf\{t\in(0,T]:c_{x,v}(t)=0\}$ (with some subtleties when $x_0\in\partial M$).